# Автоматическая сортировка только определенного периода от заданного значения в данных Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Код в котором происходят все нужные преобразования для вывода нужной таблицы

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
#
data = pd.read_csv("C:\\all.csv", low_memory=False)
table = data[["Id","Period","b","a"]]

cols = ["a","b"]

table1=table.eval("d = {}".format("+".join(cols))).drop(columns=cols)

tablefinal = table1.query("'2019-08-10' <= Period < '2019-08-11'")

matrix = pd.pivot_table (tablefinal, index="Period", columns="Id", fill_value=0)
```

Пример части таблицы которая выходит после выполнения кода, по столбцам идет ID, по строкам идет время, выгружено за 2 суток:

```
                            1120    1221    4534    1244    1563    1670    1970
2019-08-10 00:00:00.000     0       10      20      30      40      50      13
2019-08-10 01:00:00.000     0       10      20      30      40      50      13
2019-08-10 02:00:00.000     2       12      0       31      41      51      67
2019-08-10 03:00:00.000     3       0       22      0       0       0       0
2019-08-10 04:00:00.000     0       16      0       33      43      53      1
2019-08-10 05:00:00.000     5       18      24      34      44      0       1
2019-08-10 06:00:00.000     6       0       0       35      45      55      100
2019-08-10 07:00:00.000     7       22      26      36      0       56      0
2019-08-10 08:00:00.000     0       24      27      37      47      57      56
2019-08-10 09:00:00.000     9       0       0       38      48      58      0
2019-08-10 10:00:00.000     0       28      0       39      49      0       0
2019-08-10 11:00:00.000     11      30      30      40      50      60      0
2019-08-10 12:00:00.000     12      32      31      41      51      0       0
2019-08-10 13:00:00.000     2       12      0       31      41      51      67
2019-08-10 14:00:00.000     3       0       22      0       0       0       0
2019-08-10 15:00:00.000     0       16      0       33      43      53      1
2019-08-10 16:00:00.000     5       18      24      34      44      0       1
2019-08-10 17:00:00.000     6       0       0       35      45      55      100
2019-08-10 18:00:00.000     7       22      26      36      0       56      0
2019-08-10 19:00:00.000     0       24      27      37      47      57      56
2019-08-10 20:00:00.000     9       0       0       38      48      58      0
2019-08-10 21:00:00.000     0       28      0       39      49      0       0
2019-08-10 22:00:00.000     11      30      30      40      50      60      0
2019-08-10 23:00:00.000     12      32      31      41      51      0       0
2019-08-11 00:00:00.000     0       10      20      30      40      50      13
2019-08-11 00:01:00.000     2       12      0       31      41      51      67
2019-08-11 00:02:00.000     3       0       22      0       0       0       0
2019-08-11 00:03:00.000     0       16      0       33      43      53      1
2019-08-11 00:04:00.000     5       18      24      34      44      0       1
2019-08-11 00:05:00.000     6       0       0       35      45      55      100
2019-08-11 00:06:00.000     7       22      26      36      0       56      0
2019-08-11 00:07:00.000     0       24      27      37      47      57      56
2019-08-11 00:08:00.000     9       0       0       38      48      58      0
2019-08-11 00:09:00.000     0       28      0       39      49      0       0
2019-08-11 00:10:00.000     11      30      30      40      50      60      0
2019-08-11 00:11:00.000     12      32      31      41      51      0       0
2019-08-11 00:12:00.000     3       0       22      0       0       0       0
2019-08-11 00:13:00.000     0       16      0       33      43      53      1
2019-08-11 00:14:00.000     5       18      24      34      44      0       1
2019-08-11 00:15:00.000     6       0       0       35      45      55      100
2019-08-11 00:16:00.000     7       22      26      36      0       56      0
2019-08-11 00:17:00.000     0       24      27      37      47      57      56
2019-08-11 00:18:00.000     9       0       0       38      48      58      0
2019-08-11 00:19:00.000     0       28      0       39      49      0       0
2019-08-11 00:20:00.000     11      30      30      40      50      60      0
2019-08-11 00:21:00.000     12      32      31      41      51      0       0
2019-08-11 00:22:00.000     6       0       0       35      45      55      100
2019-08-11 00:23:00.000     7       22      26      36      0       56      0
```

В примере таблицы 2 суток, но в итоговую таблицу необходимо вывести только сутки, причем от заданной даты.

Идея в том, что нужно задать условное время, допустим, это 2019-08-11 10.00.00.000 дня, и выходит с 00.00 до 10.00 в таблицу записывается текущей день, то есть 2019-08-11, а после 10.00 до 00.00 значения предыдущего дня (2019-08-10), и по мере продвижения реального времени, то есть следом 11.00, 12.00 - значения в таблице смещались автоматически.

Еще пример, если взять 15.00. То с 00.00 до 15.00 значения записываются с текущего дня (2019-08-11), а после 15.00 записываются значения с 15.00 по 00.00 предыдущего дня (2019-08-10).

Принцип работы: по мере продвижения времени, текущей день по тихоньку перезаписывает значения предыдущего дня и все это в рамках 24 часов.

Это время нужно брать с времени ПК, но пока не дошел до этого момента. Думаю пока время отсчета условно задавать.

Пример выводимых данных:

```
2019-08-11 00:00:00.000     0       10      20      30      40      50      13
2019-08-11 00:01:00.000     2       12      0       31      41      51      67
2019-08-11 00:02:00.000     3       0       22      0       0       0       0
2019-08-11 00:03:00.000     0       16      0       33      43      53      1
2019-08-11 00:04:00.000     5       18      24      34      44      0       1
2019-08-11 00:05:00.000     6       0       0       35      45      55      100
2019-08-11 00:06:00.000     7       22      26      36      0       56      0
2019-08-11 00:07:00.000     0       24      27      37      47      57      56
2019-08-11 00:08:00.000     9       0       0       38      48      58      0      от 00.00 до 10.00 текущей день, 
2019-08-11 00:09:00.000     0       28      0       39      49      0       0               то есть 08.11
2019-08-11 00:10:00.000     11      30      30      40      50      60      0  <<<<<<< актуальная дата >>>>>>>
2019-08-10 11:00:00.000     11      30      30      40      50      60      0    после 10.00 до 00.00 предыдущий день,
2019-08-10 13:00:00.000     2       12      0       31      41      51      67             то есть 08.10
2019-08-10 12:00:00.000     12      32      31      41      51      0       0
2019-08-10 14:00:00.000     3       0       22      0       0       0       0
2019-08-10 15:00:00.000     0       16      0       33      43      53      1
2019-08-10 16:00:00.000     5       18      24      34      44      0       1
2019-08-10 17:00:00.000     6       0       0       35      45      55      100
2019-08-10 18:00:00.000     7       22      26      36      0       56      0
2019-08-10 19:00:00.000     0       24      27      37      47      57      56
2019-08-10 20:00:00.000     9       0       0       38      48      58      0
2019-08-10 21:00:00.000     0       28      0       39      49      0       0
2019-08-10 22:00:00.000     11      30      30      40      50      60      0
2019-08-10 23:00:00.000     12      32      31      41      51      0       0
```

Еще пример:

```
2019-08-11 00:00:00.000     0       10      20      30      40      50      13
2019-08-11 00:01:00.000     2       12      0       31      41      51      67
2019-08-11 00:02:00.000     3       0       22      0       0       0       0
2019-08-11 00:03:00.000     0       16      0       33      43      53      1
2019-08-11 00:04:00.000     5       18      24      34      44      0       1
2019-08-11 00:05:00.000     6       0       0       35      45      55      100
2019-08-11 00:06:00.000     7       22      26      36      0       56      0
2019-08-11 00:07:00.000     0       24      27      37      47      57      56
2019-08-11 00:08:00.000     9       0       0       38      48      58      0
2019-08-11 00:09:00.000     0       28      0       39      49      0       0
2019-08-11 00:10:00.000     11      30      30      40      50      60      0
2019-08-11 00:11:00.000     12      32      31      41      51      0       0
2019-08-11 00:12:00.000     3       0       22      0       0       0       0
2019-08-11 00:13:00.000     0       16      0       33      43      53      1  от 00.00 до 10.00 текущей день,
2019-08-11 00:14:00.000     5       18      24      34      44      0       1         то есть 08.11
2019-08-11 00:15:00.000     6       0       0       35      45      55      100 << Актуальная дата >>
2019-08-10 16:00:00.000     5       18      24      34      44      0       1    после 15.00 предыдущий день,
2019-08-10 17:00:00.000     6       0       0       35      45      55      100      то есть 08.10
2019-08-10 18:00:00.000     7       22      26      36      0       56      0
2019-08-10 19:00:00.000     0       24      27      37      47      57      56
2019-08-10 20:00:00.000     9       0       0       38      48      58      0
2019-08-10 21:00:00.000     0       28      0       39      49      0       0
2019-08-10 22:00:00.000     11      30      30      40      50      60      0
2019-08-10 23:00:00.000     12      32      31      41      51      0       0
```

Надеюсь доступно изъяснил.

Answer (score 4):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то можно воспользоваться [df.index.get_loc()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_loc.html):

```
In [144]: idx = df.index.get_loc("2019-08-11 00:05:00")

In [145]: df.iloc[idx-6:idx+6]
Out[145]:
                     1120  1221  4534  1244  1563  1670  1970
2019-08-10 23:59:00    12    32    31    41    51     0     0
2019-08-11 00:00:00     0    10    20    30    40    50    13
2019-08-11 00:01:00     2    12     0    31    41    51    67
2019-08-11 00:02:00     3     0    22     0     0     0     0
2019-08-11 00:03:00     0    16     0    33    43    53     1
2019-08-11 00:04:00     5    18    24    34    44     0     1
2019-08-11 00:05:00     6     0     0    35    45    55   100   #  <--- заданное время
2019-08-11 00:06:00     7    22    26    36     0    56     0
2019-08-11 00:07:00     0    24    27    37    47    57    56
2019-08-11 00:08:00     9     0     0    38    48    58     0
2019-08-11 00:09:00     0    28     0    39    49     0     0
2019-08-11 00:10:00    11    30    30    40    50    60     0
```

---

**UPDATE:**

```
In [165]: time_val = "2019-08-10 23:49:00"

In [166]: idx = df.index.get_loc(time_val)

In [167]: res = df.iloc[max(idx-6, 0) : idx+6]

In [168]: res
Out[168]:
                     1120  1221  4534  1244  1563  1670  1970
2019-08-10 23:48:00     0    10    20    30    40    50    13
2019-08-10 23:49:00     2    12     0    31    41    51    67  # < ---
2019-08-10 23:50:00     3     0    22     0     0     0     0
2019-08-10 23:51:00     0    16     0    33    43    53     1
2019-08-10 23:52:00     5    18    24    34    44     0     1
2019-08-10 23:53:00     6     0     0    35    45    55   100
2019-08-10 23:54:00     7    22    26    36     0    56     0
```

Comment: спасибо, там идея в том что что заданное время может быть выше к примеру 00.01.00, то есть в этом случае до 2 строки и после 8 строк, то есть заданое время может менятья и оно не всегда должно быть в центре

Comment: проще будет наверное объяснить на другом примере, выгружаю 2 суток полных, но в итоговую таблицу попадают только одни полные сутки, это уже работает, но необходимо еще реализовать чтобы в итогую таблицу все выводилось от заданного времени, к примеру берем 10 часов дня след дня, то выходит что с 00.00 до 10 часов дня в таблице будет новы результат то есть текущий день, а после 10 часов старый результат то есть прошлого дня и по мере того как время идет вперед, таблица перезаписывается

Comment: @Евгений, теперь вообще ничего не понятно...

Comment: @Евгений, посмотрите UPDATE - вы такой результат хотите получить?

Comment: то есть в итогой таблице всегда 24 часа. просто заданное время может быть в любом месте из этих 24 часов

Comment: @Евгений, т.е. задается только время (без даты)?

Comment: посмотрел, почти то что надо.

Comment: Дата должна задаваться с даты ПК, но пока пробую условно задавать, дата выглядит как в примере 2019-08-10 23:57:00.000

Comment: наверное будет удобнее, показать на картинке, у меня утро нужно бежать, приду вечером, нарисую картинки, несколько примеров, думаю так будет лучше

Comment: переписал вопрос с примерами, надеюсь понятнее.

Answer (score 3):

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-    

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, date, time

np.random.seed(int((datetime.timestamp(datetime.now()) % 1)*1000000/3))

# загружаем данные
dff = pd.read_csv('st9.csv', parse_dates=True)

# Текущая дата и время - просто для примера
print(datetime.now())

# сколько строк вверх и вниз выводить = 6
rows = 6
# берем случайную строку но чтобы не вылезти за пределы
rown = int((len(dff)-rows-rows)*np.random.rand()+rows)
print(rown)

# Выводит от -6 до +6 от заданной rown
print(dff.iloc[(rown-rows):(rown+rows+1)])
```

Comment: Спасибо, попробую переделать) а можно как то автоматом строки выводить, в данном примере 6 до и 6 после, но если время взять другое допустим 2019-08-11 00.05.00.000, то выходит до будет 10 строк, а после 2, это к примеру. Я наверное вопрос не совсем понятно написал

Comment: А можно мне как бы палец вверх поставить? Если не затруднит конечно.

Comment: прошу простить, забыл сразу поставить)

Comment: @Евгений всё можно сделать при должной сноровке и желании. 
переделайте тогда rown чтобы он был в диапазоне от первой строки до последней и добавьте две проверки для обрезания верхней границы и нижней. Но я так понял задача вообще стояла выводить по текущей дате, это просто для примера. Так как текущая дата не попадала в датасет то я не стал к ней привязываться.